# Displaying mysql data through hidden field values

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to display mysql records through hidden field values, but nothing displays.
A little help!

Here's the code;
Html:

```
<form name="form11" method="post" action="hpdata.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="pro" id="pro" type="hidden"  value= "CMS" />
    <input name="piror" id="piror" type="hidden"  value= "P1" />
    <input name="stat" id="stat" type="hidden"  value= "In Progress" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="groovybutton" value="...">              
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $project = $_POST["pro"];
    $pirority = $_POST["piror"];
    $status = $_POST["stat"];
    mysql_connect ("one", "two", "three");
    mysql_select_db ("wsms");
    $rest = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sheet WHERE project='$project' AND 
        pirority='$pirority' AND status='$status'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rest))
    {
        echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['date']; echo "<br>";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Where's the code which put values into fields? Right now you just echo values without placing'em into `value`-attribute.

Comment: run direct SQL using echo "SELECT * FROM sheet WHERE project='$project' AND 
pirority='$pirority' AND status='$status'"

Comment: if hidden fields wont display, you change into text and view your result or view source...

Comment: i am sending hidden values and through these values, displaying data on another php page.

Comment: So what result does the query return? are there records for those values

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU. I want the fields to be hidden!

Comment: So you have hidden fields on your form. Then in php sample code you're submitting form. What's the prblem you have?

Comment: Are you sure that the field is named `pirority` and not `priority`, does the query return any error? you should look for those too

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ the field name is correct! the query return nothing.

Comment: @MOZ can you do a var_dump($_POST) in your php file to see whether data is getting posted or not. There might be some configuration issue which is resulting into data not getting posted.

Comment: if the query returns nothing, then there are no such records for those values, simple. Are you aware of `mysql_error()` and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `isset` into your php code

Example

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   echo  $project = $_POST["pro"]."<br>";
    echo $pirority = $_POST["piror"]."<br>";
    echo $status = $_POST["stat"];
   /* mysql_connect ("one", "two", "three");
    mysql_select_db ("wsms");
    $rest = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sheet WHERE project='$project' AND 
        pirority='$pirority' AND status='$status'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rest))
    {
        echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['date']; echo "<br>";
    }*/
}
?>
<form name="form11" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="pro" id="pro" type="hidden"  value= "CMS" />
    <input name="piror" id="piror" type="hidden"  value= "P1" />
    <input name="stat" id="stat" type="hidden"  value= "In Progress" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="groovybutton" value="...">              
  </form>
```

Output

```
CMS
P1
In Progress
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that if the data is coming in the post or not:

```
<?php

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($_POST);
   exit;

?>
```

If yes than remove the print code i provided , and use extract($_POST); at the top of your PHP code. You query will become like this:

```
$rest = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sheet WHERE project='$pro' AND 
        pirority='$piror' AND status='$stat'");
```

Comment: Its displaying Array,

Array
(
    [pro] => CMS
    [piror] => P1
    [stat] => In Progress
    [submit] => ...
)

Comment: But it still displaying nothing after changing the query.

Comment: Did you used extract POST?